# UIView display behind the Uipopoverviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I have application in that first i add viewcontroller and in that i open one UIPopoverviewcontroller and now i want to add one view top of every view including popoverview i add the view in window but it is not showing top. It shows behind the popoverview. can any one have idea. please help me.

Comment: Try to set Tag  = 2000.

Comment: add that view to popover or just create another popover

Comment: @ Himanshu Joshi it is big project so i cant send you. jut i want to know that i have one viewcontroller and it that i have one popoverview and now i add one view in viewcontroller and it shows top of all the view including popoverview.